# Magento: getProductUrl not returning URL ReWrites

Tags: php, magento

To my utter frustration I don't seem to be able to get the following code to deliver the results I am looking for.

The URLs served from the following code look like this...

> mywebsite.co.uk/catalog/product/view/id/5980/s/classic-army-ca063m-stoner-lmg-aeg/category/263/

The desired result I seek would be more in-tune with this...

> mywebsite.co.uk/classic-army-ca063m-stoner-lmg-aeg.html

or this...

> mywebsite.co.uk/aegs/classic-army-ca063m-stoner-lmg-aeg.html

I spent quite a few hours, I am afraid to say, reading and experimenting with alternative code suggestions but this tired, knackerd old goat just isn't able to figure it out. So if anyone could extend the hand of goodwill and show me the error of my ways I would be greatly appreciative.

```
public function _construct() {
    parent::_construct();
    $this->_init('pticker/pticker');
}

public function fetchProducts() {
    $_productCollection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();
    $_productCollection->addFieldToFilter(array
        (array('attribute' => 'Status', 'eq' => '1'),
    ));
    $_productCollection->addFieldToFilter(array
        (array('attribute' => 'appearinticker', 'eq' => '1'),
    ));

    $product = array();
    $linkText= Mage::getStoreConfig('pticker/color/linktext');
    if($linkText == ''){$linkText = 100;}
    if (count($_productCollection) > 0) {
        $count = 0;
        $i = 0;
        foreach ($_productCollection as $_product) {
            $model = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');
            $_product = $model->load($_product->getId());
            $title= $_product->getTickertitle();
            if($title == ''){$title = $_product->getName();}
            if(strlen($title) > $linkText){
            $title = substr($title,0, $linkText);
            $title .= '...';
            }
            $product[$i]['title'] = htmlspecialchars($title);
            $product[$i]['link'] = $model->getProductUrl();
            $i++;
        }
    }
   // print_r($product);
    return $product;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 
$_productCollection->addFieldToFilter(array
        (array('attribute' => 'appearinticker', 'eq' => '1'),
    ));


//add below line after product collection filter to rewrite URL  .

$_productCollection->addUrlRewrite();
```